# How do I make a synchronous call to an async method in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await

I have an async method for example `async methodA()`,
I want `methodB()` to not be async but to call `methodA()`.
How do I get `methodA()` to finish and send data to `methodB()`?

Comment: You don't.  Embrace the asynchronicity of JS, don't fight it.

Comment: What do you mean by `to not be async`?

Comment: I think what OP is trying to say is that how the output of method A which is async can be used in method B which is not async. please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: that's right... I need method b to not be async...

Comment: `async` is an alternative thing of `Promise`, or more before: `callback`, so if you don't want `methodB` to be async, use `Promise` or `callback` instead.

Comment: You can't.  Any method that calls something async and uses that result in its result is automatically async.  There is no way around that in Javascript.  Async functions finish sometime LATER, after the calling function returns and there's simply no way around that so you can't make a synchronous function that calls something async.  Can't do it.  Async is infectious.  Anything that calls it becomes async too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async/await` .
Let's take your method A which is async. Make your method A async by using `async` keyword.

```
async function A(){
//do something
}
```

Now function A always return a `promise` if it doesn't return JavaScript wraps it around into a resolved `promise`

Make your method B to wait until that promise settles and return it's result

```
let value = await promise;
```

Now this only works inside `async` function. And you can use `value` in method B.
With this you can use the output of method A in method B
You can also assign your output to a global variable and use it later

```js
async function A() {
          let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => resolve("output for method B"), 1000)
          });
          let result = await promise; // wait till the promise resolves (*)
          function B(){
            // do something with result
            console.log(result)
          }
          B(result)
        }
        A();
```

Comment: to use `await` author should declare `methodB` to be `async` also. but he asks if he can omit that.

Comment: @skyboyer It's not required to declare the `methodB` to be `async` if it's not needed. And according to OP `methodB` is synchronous

Comment: @Lokesh: but you can't `await` in a non-`async` method.

Comment: but can't the async ethod wait to return something?

Comment: @WiktorZychla Yea you are right `await` works only inside `async` method

Comment: @brainstormtrooper `let result = await promise` this wait for the async method to return something

Comment: @brainstormtrooper check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: @Lokesh `await` **doesn't** wait. It only means the remaining code is automatically pushed into the continuation.

Comment: @WiktorZychla According to the link which I have mentioned in one of my comment above. It says " An async function can contain an await expression that pauses the execution of the async function and waits for the passed Promise's resolution, and then resumes the async function's execution and returns the resolved value. "

Answer (score 0):

Well, It's not exactly possible without a timeout and I didn't want one of those so I made the whole thing async...